# How do I deny access to invalid web subdomains with .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

The following .htaccess file does not work:

```
SSLrequireSSL

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^secure\.neuralfutures\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) - [F]
```

I'm trying to prevent access to anything but "https://secure.neuralfutures.com/docs/", i.e. "https://www.neuralfutures.com/docs/" will fail.

I also seem to be running into caching issues: if I upload the new .htaccess with CuteFTP, then do a file refresh in FireFox, it doesn't seem to have any effect on the output at all. I can tell this because if I comment out SSLrequireSSL, it still disallows a http:// request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why dont you try this

```
SSLrequireSSL

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^secure\.neuralfutures\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://secure.neuralfutures.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NC,L]
```

Abt caching - May be your web hosting provider has some caching in place, but not very sure abt this.